# CSS Grid: 3x3 grid to fill the remaining space of the parent

Tags: html, css, css-grid

How do I create a 3x3 grid that fills the entire container (the yellow bordered box)?

[image]

Here's what I've tried so far but this does not seem to work.
basically, what I want to achieve is if there are only 6 items, the rows should be only just 2.
and if there are more than 6 and less than 9, the rows should be 3.

I'm not sure if this is doable in CSS Grid or in CSS at all. I'm happy to use javascript if it's not possible to do in CSS.

```
.container {
    gap: 15px;
    display: grid;
    overflow: auto;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, minmax(250px, 300px));
    grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `grid-auto-rows` **only** and `max-height` for the container to allow it to shrink if you have less than 3 rows.

example

- `minmax()` down-scale for the demo, use your own values.
- `max-height` it be set at least for 3 rows take the max from `mimmax()` value (x3) +  `gap` value (x2).

```css
.container {
  gap: 15px;
  display: grid;
  overflow: auto;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(50px, 60px);/* initial values where 250px,300px */
  position: relative;
  max-height: 950px;/* = 3 rows + 2 gaps + eventual extra padding/border */
  border:solid tomato;
}

/* irrelevant CSS for demo purpose from here */

.container {
  counter-reset: divs;
  margin:2em;
  background:gray;
}
div div {
  border: solid;
  background:white;
  display:flex;
  min-width:50px
}
div div:before {
  counter-increment: divs;
  content: counter(divs);
  margin:auto;
}

body {display:flex;align-items:start}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>


<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```